# Doing async io in the loop

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have following async python code:

```
async def generate_pdf(self):
    for i in range(100):
        data_bytes = await process_pdf(self.xsl, xml_data)
        pallet_pdf = PdfReader(fdata=data_bytes)
        pallet_pdf_output.addpage(pallet_pdf.getPage(i))

async def process_pdf(xsl, xml_data):
    res_status, data_bytes = transform_document_api(xml_data, xsl)
    return data_bytes
```

Here `generate_pdf` `async` function makes 100 api calls via `async process_pdf`. Returned data is than pushed to `PDFReader`. The question is, does `PdfReader` functionality linearise `for`-loop api calls? So, at every loop step, `PdfReader` will wait until `process_pdf` returns result, so there is no real async io.

Comment: `await` is blocking so your for loop runs sequentially. You might want to take a look as `as_completed`.

Comment: `await` doesn't mean "go do this in another thread and keep going". `await` means "stop this thread and go do other stuff while you're waiting". It's the exact opposite of what you're trying to do, from the sound of it.